# MediaPlayer throw Exception in android ICS

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

I use `MediaPlayer` to stream mp3 radio station , it works fine on all android versions except in Android 4.0 it throw this exception

```
05-28 19:29:57.160: E/MediaPlayer(6854): Unable to to create media player
05-28 19:29:57.164: W/System.err(6854): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
05-28 19:29:57.164: W/System.err(6854):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
05-28 19:29:57.164: W/System.err(6854):     at biz.dot.hayatfm.RadioPlayerService$1.run(RadioPlayerService.java:50)
05-28 19:29:57.168: W/System.err(6854):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

here is the code

```
this.mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
this.mediaPlayer.setDataSource( Uri.parse("http://vpr.streamguys.net/vpr96.mp3").toString());
                this.mediaPlayer.prepare();
                this.mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Check this thread out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798227/android-mediaplayer-setdatasource-issue-for-downloaded-media-file

Comment: Whats the input that you are giving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `IOException` you got infer that the `MediaPlayer` class uses a `URL` to stream and it can access it so it will throw an `IOException` android 4.0 need the internet permission to stream form url  this was not the case for pre android 4.0 so you could stream music as you want without that permission.

to fix this include this permssion in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```